How can i have 1 package.json file in a react app or run a script?
I have a react and there is a package.json file in the main project and then there is one ion the ClientApp.
So when i start the project I need to do an npm install on the main and the move to the ClientApp and do it there to restore all packages.
Can i some how have only one package in the solution that is for bot the Server(backend) and Client (frontend)  ?
I have tried adding a script to the package.json file that a user can run .. For example it may be called appinstall.bat and then on the Console prompt the user types .. npm run appinstall , but that didnt work as i dont know how to change directory when i need to do the npm install on the clientpp.
Also in the package.json file there are some packages that need to be installed , like msal-react , msal-browser. But when i try it on another machine it says it cant install them , why would that happen if they are in the package.json to be installed ?
